# Finding certain words in single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to find specific word out of a list of words in a single cell and output a value if true but I think i'm taking the wrong approach for this issue.

Basically I get a description text in a cell and if in that cell exists one of these specific words it should return a value if true.

**Numbers , reporting ,jobs ,administration**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("numb3r5";X16));"numb3r5";
    IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Administration";X16));"AdminNumbers";
       IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Reporting";X16));"Reporting";
          IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Job";X16));"Jobs";
             IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("numbers";X16));"numb3r5";
                NA())))))
```

I got this very complicated nested IF formula which kind of does the trick but for example in the following text the word **"Reporting"** is above **"Numbers"** it will be ignored because it will first search for "Numbers" because this is the first IF statement and it returns TRUE and exits the formula and never reaches the **Reporting** If statement.

**Sample text:**

> Solution KR00040079:
> Technische Störung:
> Reporting
> AW meldet einen Fehlermeldung beim Anmelden von Numbers.
> (siehe Attachment)
> AW habe diese Fehlermeldung seit ca heute um 9.

It returns "Numbers" here because it is the first statement and its through after scanning the whole text in that cell.

Is there any otherway this could be done ? A formula that would search for multiple values within order of how the text is formatted ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,{"Numb3r5","Reporting","Jobs","administration"},Y,{"Numbers","Reporting","Jobs","administration"},Z,SORT(CHOOSE({1,2},X,SEARCH(Y,A1)),2),IF(ISNUMBER(INDEX(Z,1,2)),INDEX(Z,1,1),"Not Available"))
```

Comment: Great - just one enhancement: I would always put the words to look for into a table that could be changed by the user without changing the formula ...

Comment: @Ike, these are arrays that are interchangeable with range references.

Comment: Yes - I now - it's more for all those learning the new formulas :-)

Comment: Wow. "learning the new formulas" - I am so far behind I've given up :)

Comment: Hi @JvdV this unfortunatly returns me only "Not Available" for some reason... I did the same test on a new sheet.

Comment: Do you have ms365? And also, what locale language settings do you use? Especially the `CHOOSE({1,2}` part is sensitive to other delimiters. For example, over here in the Dutch version of ms365 I'd have to use `{1\2}` @TerraceGrow. Otherwise it's best to go over the formula in steps using 'Evaluate Formula' and see if all steps are handles correctly.

Comment: My pc uses ; instead of , I think its related to this... I did change the commas for semi columns but this gave me the return "Not available"

Comment: @TerraceGrow, hm can you try the backslash instead? Otherwise what we could do is that you share your screen through Quick Assist or some sort to debug this on your end.

Comment: On a German system you would have to use a dot `{1.2}`. Check if you have the LET-formula by typing `=LET` into the cell - if it does not occur in the list you are not on the current channel